# Dynamic Wagtail bgcolor templatetags

Tags: django, wagtail, templatetags

I am trying to get a **dynamic background color** with Wagtail templatetags when I convert an image like this :

```
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}
{% image my_file width-768 format-jpeg bgcolor-171721 as image_jpeg %}
<img src="{{ image_jpeg.url }}"/>
```

How I can change the value `bgcolor-171721` with a dynamic variable in my template ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to have dynamic `token` parts for a [Django Template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

However, you could generate the rendition with the dynamic parts at the request (page model). The wagtail docs explain how to [generate a rendition in Python](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html). The tokens are similar but generated as one string separated by the `|` character.

You can then pass this into the template's context via your page model's [`get_context' method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context).

**`models.py`**

```py
class MyPage(Page):
    # ...

    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include an image rendition with a dynamic bg
        context = super().get_context(request)
        # https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html
        some_dynamic_value = 'DDA0DD'
        context['image_jpeg'] = self.my_image.get_rendition('width-768|bgcolor-%s|format-jpeg' % some_dynamic_value)
        # you can use this within the template the same way - <img src="{{ image_jpeg.url }}"/>
        return context
```

You could go further and create a custom template tag that takes a dynamic background colour (or reads it from the template context) but that might not be worth the extra complexity.